# Calculate number of weeks left until expire date

Tags: formula, formula-field, date

I have a field called 'Membership_Expire_Date'. I want to calculate the total number of weeks left for a membership to expire. It is easy to calculate number of days with formula Membership_Expire_Date - Today() but how can I calculate the weeks?

Answer (score 1):

If you know the number of days and that every week has 7 days then it is just a matter of [rounding the result](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.bi_integrate_data_prep_recipe_formula_field_numericFunctions_round.htm&type=5) as required.

There is a fairly good post in the Trailblazer community on doing this - [Calculating Week count based on a date field](https://trailblazers.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000DdUkQAK). The formula that Patrick Sullivan gave:

```
ROUND((Today()-Date__c)/7,0)
```

Note, that is for dates in the past. You'll want to reverse that so you are subtracting from the date in the future. E.g.

```
ROUND((Membership_Expire_Date__c - Today())/7,0)
```

If rounding the result of the division operation isn't giving you the result you want you may need to switch to the [Floor](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.bi_integrate_data_prep_recipe_formula_field_numericFunctions_floor.htm&type=5) or [Ceiling](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.bi_integrate_data_prep_recipe_formula_field_numericFunctions_ceil.htm&type=5) functions instead.